# sys.path don't locate local dir

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, virtualbox

I've been trying to import a models file inside a seeder command.

I've tried `from ...models import Player`,  `from winners.models import Player` added `__init__.py` everything that could be possible right.

And I keep getting or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winners'` or  `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Although when I print the sys.path the local project ain't there. I've just started working on kali VirtualBox, could it be something wrong with the configuration?

[image]

Comment: The correct way to run management commands is to run `python manage.py <command name>`

Comment: how am i so stupid. i totally forgot this. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `models.py` is in the same folder as your script, it would be sufficient to use the following statement, without adding your folder location to `sys.path`:

```
from models import Player
```

Alternatively, you could set the `sys.path` to the path ending in "olympic"
(not "winners", since you want to refer to that folder in your `from` statement) to allow for the following:

```
from winners.models import Player
```

Comment: thanks for trying but  lain Shelvington aswered what i was dooing wrong. I was trying to call directly the file like python seeder.py .    but because its a django project i should call python manage.py seeder